# Alignment issue after opening new activity

Tags: android, alignment

I made a calculator in Android. I tried the app on my Nexus 5 and it is ok but on a Samsung GS3 I noticed when I open the History activity and come back to the Main one, every time I press a button its text align goes from center to the left.

Those are the images:

1. Before: [link](http://oi60.tinypic.com/112bhh0.jpg)
2. After: [link](http://oi58.tinypic.com/dyuq76.jpg)

This is the xml code of the first number row:

```
     <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bt1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1.5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:onClick="num_click"
                android:text="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bt2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1.5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:onClick="num_click"
                android:text="2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bt3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1.5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:onClick="num_click"
                android:text="3" />

        </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the viewground from a tablelayout to a linearlayout with horizontal orientation,and then change the widths of all the buttons in the viewgroup to 0dp.Make sure their weights are 1

Answer (score 0):

Well done Niza. I did not need to change the layout but the suggestion about the width hit the mark. However I removed all the `android:gravity` from the buttons (not needed) and everything is ok now.

Now my xml (first number row) looks like this:

```
<TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bt1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1.5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1.5dp"
                android:onClick="num_click"
                android:text="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bt2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1.5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1.5dp"
                android:onClick="num_click"
                android:text="2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bt3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1.5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1.5dp"
                android:onClick="num_click"
                android:text="3" />

        </TableRow>
```